# ErrorException in Repository.php line 367: This cache store does not support tagging

Tags: laravel-5

**.ENV**

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=array
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

**Config/cache.php**

```
'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'array'),
```

When i start serve, XAMPP start http://localhost:8000/

i read many post but i see the same error

Answer (score 1):

[Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/cache#cache-tags)

> Note: Cache tags are not supported when using the `file` or `database`
>   cache drivers. Furthermore, when using multiple tags with caches that
>   are stored "forever", performance will be best with a driver such as
>   `memcached`, which automatically purges stale records.

In other words you should use right cache driver which supports tagging, for example `memcached` or `redis`.

**.ENV**:

```
CACHE_DRIVER=memcached
```